# Accessing resource Bundles

Tags: java, android, resources, android-resources

I'm writing a localisation to a game. Sometimes game classes do not have access to application `Context` object, so instead of `strings.xml` resource I have used resource bundles for localisation. However, I am not sure whether loading strings from resource bundles affects running application seriously or not. For game it is pretty serious.

I know that resources from `strings.xml` are pre-loaded and it takes short time to access them. Does it also work for resource boundles? Will it freeze my game performance?

Comment: I think in your case, you might just take up the strings from your resource to the run-time memory, for example a `HashMap`? This will enhance the performance for sure.

Comment: @ReazMurshed, yes, I know, that will help anyway. But I was interested more theoretically than practically.